# Camera Movement - Snap Camera back to origin in relation to the player object

Tags: unity, camera

I am trying to implement camera movement like it is done in Guild Wars 2. Scenario is when A and D keys are pressed, the player rotates right / left and the camera follows and stays behind the character / player like this
(Starts at 23 seconds)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkHJ2uSrLjE

I can get the basic working fine, and I did it this way

```
private void KeysRotateCameraAndPlayer()
{
    float keysOrbitingSpeed = 120;
    this.player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        Debug.Log("Rotate Left");
        CenterPoint.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(0, 360 + Time.deltaTime * keysOrbitingSpeed, 0);
        player.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(0, 360 + Time.deltaTime * keysOrbitingSpeed, 0);

    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        Debug.Log("Rotate Right");
        CenterPoint.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 360 + Time.deltaTime * keysOrbitingSpeed, 0);
        player.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, 360 + Time.deltaTime * keysOrbitingSpeed, 0);
    }
}
```

Now the next part I am trying to achieve , when the camera is rotated / orbited around the player using the mouse and is left in a position that is not the origin i.e behind the player (in relation to player)… when A and D keys are pressed, what happens in GW2 is the camera seems to snap back to the origin and then continue to follow the player from the back ( or its relation origin with regards to the player Object if that makes sense)

This is what the game does (which I hope to achieve)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTTDaeuHl80

so at present moment with my current code
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a53lZ_0BDtg
camera and player will continue to rotate (with A and D), from where the camera was last left during orbit. How can I add to this, to force the camera to snap back to origin like they have in Guild Wars 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
void Update () {
    Camera.main.transform.position = player.transform.position -  Quaternion.Euler(player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles) * transform.forward * distance;
    Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
}
```

It will change the position and rotation and camera to make it stay behind the player. If you need to move the camera smoothly you can use `Vector3.Lerp` for position and `Quaternion.Lerp` for rotation.

```
void Update () {
    desiredPos = player.transform.position - Quaternion.Euler (player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles) * transform.forward * distance;
    desiredRot = Quaternion.Euler (0, player.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (Camera.main.transform.position, desiredPos, Time.deltaTime*camPosSpeed);
    Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (Camera.main.transform.rotation, desiredRot, Time.deltaTime*camRotSpeed);
}
```